# JQuery if element hasClass, display content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `ul` with `li`'s forming a menu with drop-downs. Every time an `li` is clicked, it gets the `"ui-state-active"`, when it's clicked again, the class is removed. I want to hide the content of the page when an `li` has that class. It should be easy but I'm running into problems, I have:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass("ui-state-active") ){
        console.log("Yes");
        mainContent.fadeOut();
    } else if ( !$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")){
        console.log("No");
        mainContent.FadeIn();
    }
})
```

It always evaluates to Yes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add html markup

Comment: Can't do, it's a client's Wordpress site

Comment: Of course you can, just copy+paste the output HTML - or even just a basic example of its structure

Comment: @Sergi yes, you can. We dont want your client site we want a [mcve]

Comment: yes @Sergi, show it, you can do it! cmon...

Comment: Also, youve not showed us how you're adding/removing the class - surely it would be in the same handler you've shown?

Comment: Your code works fine . See https://jsfiddle.net/shree/2db2kh7q/ . I remove mainContent from code because i dont know what is mainContent.

Comment: Indeed it does, even if you are toggleing the class: https://jsfiddle.net/tnnewtgh/

Comment: where is the code to remove class `ui-state-active` from clicked `li`?

Comment: You also need to toggle "ui-state-active" class.

Comment: Does the jquery ui toggle the `ui-state-active` class

Comment: Honestly, I just can't find where is the code to add and remove that class, it's a Wordpress and that part must be a plugin.

Comment: I think the code (from the naming) is coming form jquery-ui. You should find something like this in your code: $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

Answer (score 2):

I think the crux of your question is really in your last comment

> Honestly, I just can't find where is the code to add and remove that class, it's a Wordpress and that part must be a plugin.

It's almost certainly the case that the `li` click handler code you showed in your question is firing *before* the plugin is toggling the class.

The only fix for this issue is to find the plugin, check for the events it raises, and hook in to those event(s) for showing/hiding your content. There is no shortcut.

Comment: `.ui-state-active` is from jQuery UI. _"Class to be applied on mousedown to clickable button-like elements. Applies "clickable active" container styles to an element and its child text, links, and icons"._ . It could be great to know wich plugin of jQuery UI are setting this class and then use the events of this class instead of modify the source code of jQuery UI

Answer (score -1):

`$(this)` is just the clicked element. You have to query for the other elements, because the clicked now has this class as you have explained.

But this depends on the HTML markup on how to get there. Maybe you can work with jQuery.parent():
https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Something like this should work:

```
$(this).parent('ul').hasClass("ui-state-active")
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').children().each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
        console.log("Yes");
        // mainContent.fadeOut();
      } else if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
        console.log("No");
        // mainContent.FadeIn();
      }
    });

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to hit 'Post answer'? This seems to be a comment, although even then it doesn't make much sense

Comment: No, the OP says he was *toggling* the class. ("...when it's clicked again, the class is removed")

Comment: Yes right clicking on the element its getting active again

Comment: Yes its removed on the other elements but not on the one he have now clicked and this is stored in the "this"

Comment: When you run your example, you never see `Yes` in the console. I would probably expect to when clicking the same "tab" multiple times.

Comment: I also saw this, the problem is the integration of stackoverflow did't allow to load jquery-ui.

Answer (score -2):

Add below line in both of your conditions:

```
$(this).toggleClass("ui-state-active");
```